# How to get emmeans to print degrees of freedom for glmer class

Tags: r, lme4, mixed-models, emmeans

I'm trying to get the degrees of freedom from `emmeans` of a `glmer` model for reporting reasons, but they just show `Inf`.

Here's some sample data. In the real data, there is no nesting structure, this is just a consequence of how I built the data frame:

```
set.seed(1234)
dat <- data.frame(
  dv=c(rnorm(mean=1, sd=0.2, n=12000)), 
  id=c(rep(c("1", "2", "3"), times=c(4000, 4000, 4000))), 
  region=c(rep(rep(c("1", "2"), times=c(2000, 2000)), 3)), 
  intervention=c(rep(c("1", "2", "1"), times=c(4000, 4000, 4000))), 
  timepoint=c(rep(rep(c("1", "2"), times=c(2000, 2000)), times=3)), 
  direction=c(rep(rep(c("1", "2"), times=c(2000, 2000)), 3))
)

glmm_1 <- glmer(dv ~ intervention*timepoint*region + direction + (1|id), data=dat, family=gaussian(link="log"))

glmm_1_emm <- emmeans::emmeans(glmm_1, pairwise ~ intervention*region*timepoint, type = "response")

glmm_1_emm$emmeans

NOTE: A nesting structure was detected in the fitted model:
    timepoint %in% (direction*region), region %in% direction
 region timepoint direction intervention response      SE  df asymp.LCL asymp.UCL
 1      1         1         1                   1 0.00313 Inf     0.994      1.01
 2      2         2         1                   1 0.00313 Inf     0.998      1.01
 1      1         1         2                   1 0.00442 Inf     0.992      1.01
 2      2         2         2                   1 0.00442 Inf     0.995      1.01

Confidence level used: 0.95 
Intervals are back-transformed from the log scale
```

Comment: `emmeans` uses asymptotic results for all `merMod` objects unless they were fitted using `lmer()`. But if you think you know the correct df to use, you can just specify it, e.g., `emmeans(model, "treatment", df = 12)`. There is definitely a nesting structure in this examle, due to the way the factor levels relate to one another. `region`, `timepoint` and `direction` are identical so you have tons of non-estimable effects in the model.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is really more of a statistical (i.e. for [CrossValidated](https://stats.stackexchange.com)) than a computational question. **tl;dr** finite-size corrections are rarely considered for GLMs or GLMMs, and for GLMMs in particular there is little theoretical work I'm aware of that would even specify how to compute them. That's why `emmeans` etc. report `df` as `Inf`.

`df` in `emmeans` output represents the "denominator degrees of freedom" (i.e. the `nu2` value you would use if testing against an F distribution `F_{nu1,nu2}`), which is something like (number of observations - number of parameters estimated) for simple (non-mixed) models like a linear regression or simple ANOVA, but which is considerably harder to define for multilevel models (i.e. linear mixed models). For *generalized* linear (and linear mixed) models, it gets even worse. Quoting from the ["degrees of freedom" section of the GLMM FAQ](https://bbolker.github.io/mixedmodels-misc/glmmFAQ.html#why-doesnt-lme4-display-denominator-degrees-of-freedomp-values-what-other-options-do-i-have) (see there for full references):

> - When the responses are not normally distributed (as in GLMs and GLMMs), and when the scale parameter is not estimated (as in standard Poisson- and binomial-response models), then the deviance differences are only asymptotically F- or chi-square-distributed (i.e. not for our real, finite-size samples). In standard GLM practice, we usually ignore this problem; there is some literature on finite-size corrections for GLMs under the rubrics of “Bartlett corrections” and “higher order asymptotics” (see McCullagh and Nelder (1989), Cordeiro, Paula, and Botter (1994), Cordeiro and Ferrari (1998) and the cond package (on CRAN) [which works with GLMs, not GLMMs]), but it’s rarely used. (The bias correction/Firth approach implemented in the brglm package attempts to address the problem of finite-size bias, not finite-size non-chi-squaredness of the deviance differences.)
> - When the scale parameter in a GLM is estimated rather than fixed (as in Gamma or quasi-likelihood models), it is sometimes recommended to use an F
>   test to account for the uncertainty of the scale parameter (e.g. Venables and Ripley (2002) recommend anova(...,test="F") for quasi-likelihood models)
>   Combining these issues, one has to look pretty hard for information on small-sample or finite-size corrections for GLMMs: Feng, Braun, and McCulloch (2004) and Bell and Grunwald (2010) look like good starting points, but it’s not at all trivial.

Comment: It's not always residual d.f. For `lmer` models, for example, by default we use Kendall-Roger to determine d.f., and that often is different for each estimate.

Comment: I guess I meant "denominator df"

Comment: Thank you both @RussLenth and BenBolker for the explanation. In that case, is there any guidance you can provide for writing up the emmeans results of multiple comparisons from a lognormal GLMM?

Comment: Is there any particular reason you're using a log-link GLMM rather than `lmer(log(y) ~ ...)` ?  Guidance on writing up the results would be a [CrossValidated](https://stats.stackexchange.com) question, I think ...

Comment: @BenBolker I'm concerned that [ln(|)] and ln([(|]) are not the same since ultimately the precision of my DV measures is important to this question.

Comment: If you're going to call what you do a "lognormal GLMM", then I think doing it the way Ben suggests with `lmer(log(y) ~ ...)` as the response is the more appropriate way to do it.

Comment: The most important question (this is definitely devolving into a CV conversation/question) is whether you want to assume the variance is independent of the mean (glmer with log link) or proportional to the mean^2 (i.e., constant CV: lmer with log response). I agree with @RussLenth that the latter is usually the more important default. You can do bias correction (see emmeans vignettes) to compensate for the nonlinear-averaging issue ...

Comment: @BenBolker I was unaware of the bias.adj=TRUE option, THANK YOU this is much simpler.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently `emmeans::emmeans` calculates `Inf` degrees of freedom, not sure why. But I've spotted this:

```
str(glmm_1_emm$emmeans)
# 'emmGrid' object with variables:
#   region = 1, 2
# timepoint = 1, 2
# direction = 1, 2
# intervention = 1, 2
# Nesting structure:  timepoint %in% (direction*region), region %in% direction
# Transformation: “log” 
# Some things are non-estimable (null space dim = 5)  ## <--------------------- !!!
```

There's a summary method involved, `emmeans:::summary.emmGrid`, since the summary is not calculated until you print it, i.e. evaluate `glmm_1_emm$emmeans`.

Provided that the degrees of freedom are correct later on, then you could extract them using a rather artless `capture.output` approach:

```
tmp <- capture.output(glmm_1_emm$emmeans)
res <- read.table(text=tmp[1:(which(tmp == '') - 1)], header=TRUE)
res
#   region timepoint direction intervention response      SE  df asymp.LCL asymp.UCL
# 1      1         1         1            1        1 0.00313 Inf     0.994      1.01
# 2      2         2         2            1        1 0.00313 Inf     0.998      1.01
# 3      1         1         1            2        1 0.00442 Inf     0.992      1.01
# 4      2         2         2            2        1 0.00442 Inf     0.995      1.01

res[, 7]  ## degrees of freedom
# [1] Inf Inf Inf Inf
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment, I'm trying to print the degrees if freedom, not the results. I keep getting Inf instead of a number.

Comment: @myfatson Aha, sorry in my edit to your question I first misinterpreted your 'df' acronym. Hmm, for some reason `emmeans` calculates in fact `Inf` degrees of freedom, so it's rather an issue of how to calculate them differently than extract them out of the emmeans object. See the  issue though I've spotted in edited answer. Maybe ask that one better on [Cross Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). Cheers!